# Why this angular $http.put parameter won't get passed?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I am facing a very weird case in my angularjs app. In a factory, the following code works properly:

```
$http.put(apiBase + 'delete?id='+orderId);
```

Which obviously connects to an api to perform a PUT operation (it is called "delete" here but it actually only updates a flag in the record).

But the same code, when written this way, does not work:

```
$http.put(apiBase + 'delete', {
    params: {
      id: orderId
    }
  }
);
```

Which is funny, because I am using the exact same syntax in some other factories to hit similar APIs and they work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using $http.put, you don't need to wrap your data in the config object.  You can pass the data object directly, and then omit the third parameter:

```
$http.put(apiBase + 'delete', { id: orderId });
```

Your other factories probably work with the syntax stated in your question because you are making $http.get or $http.delete requests.

I have found that this slightly-different API  for the various "shortcut" methods to be confusing enough that I almost think it's better to avoid them altogether.  You can see the differences from [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) where get and delete have two parameters:

```
get(url, [config]);
delete(url, [config]);
```

and most of the other shortcut methods have three:

```
post(url, data, [config]);
put(url, data, [config]);
```

Note that the `[config]` object is defined further up on that documentation page, which is where it defines that "params" property:

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET
>   parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because the second argument of `$http.put()` is a `data` object, not a `config` object. You are passing a `config` object as the second parameter.

You could try:

```
$http.put(apiBase + 'delete', null, {
    params: {
      id: orderId
    }
  }
);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put

Comment: Although this will work, it's more idiomatic to include the payload of a PUT request in the "data" property (which goes into the request body), rather than the "params" property of the config object (which generates query string parameters).  I realize you are just building off of the code the OP already was using, this is more of an "FYI."